# Error: release helm-kibana-security failed: timed out waiting for the condition

Tags: security, kibana, kubernetes-helm

I have been using helm chart to install elasticserahc and kibana into kubernetes,

using the defualt configuration everything went ok but I want to enable the security on both elasticsearch and kibana
I didi what's recommanded in the documentation , the security was enabled for elasticsearch but I have probleme upgrading kibana with security configuratuion it gives me this error :

Error: release helm-kibana-security failed: timed out waiting for the condition

once I run make ( from /kibana/examples/security )

I even tried to install is directly without using the Makefile :
helm install --wait --timeout=600 --values ./security.yml --name helm-kibana-security ../../

but having the same issue , can any one help me please

Answer (score 0):

"failed: timed out waiting for the condition"

This message occurs when you install a release with the --wait flag, however, the pods are unable to start for some reason.

The problem is most likely in "./security.yml"

try running the below commands to debug the issue:

```
kubectl describe pod kibana-pod-name
kubectl logs kibana-pod-name
```

Comment: thank you for your help , I fixed some issues but still having this problem 2019-07-07 08:05:45.234 HAEO
FATAL Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line

Answer (score 0):

this is the security.yml file

```
---

elasticsearchHosts: "https://security-master:9200"

extraEnvs:
  - name: 'ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME'
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: elastic-credentials
        key: username
  - name: 'ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD'
    valueFrom:
      secretKeyRef:
        name: elastic-credentials
        key: password

kibanaConfig:
  kibana.yml: |
    server.ssl:
      enabled: true
      key: /usr/share/kibana/config/certs/kibana/kibana.key
      certificate: /usr/share/kibana/config/certs/kibana/kibana.crt
    xpack.security.encryptionKey: something_at_least_32_characters
    elasticsearch.ssl:
      certificateAuthorities: /usr/share/kibana/config/certs/elastic-certificate.pem
      verificationMode: certificate
protocol: https

secretMounts:
  - name: elastic-certificate-pem
    secretName: elastic-certificate-pem
    path: /usr/share/kibana/config/certs
  - name: kibana-certificates
    secretName: kibana-certificates
path: /usr/share/kibana/config/certs/kibana
```